# Browser hangs for after computing intense JS function in a loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, browser, event-handling, dom-events

My problem requires the below function to run in a loop on an average of 20 iterations

```
var test = function() {
  // some logic which take about 0.5 sec to execute
  // and deal with DOM manipulation
};
```

so if I iterate over it 20 items it will take an average of 10 sec and in the meantime browser hangs (not able to scroll down).

So I tried to change it to something like this

```
var test = function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      // some logic which take about 0.5 sec to execute
      // 0.5 sec as it deals with DOM manipulation
   }, 0);
};
```

so that browser gets time to execute after each time Out but still the browser in hanging.

Why it is so? This is what I have always read in theory but not working practically.

Comment: In your code setTimeOut is written like this?

Comment: I would spend time examining why it is that on even a modest modern computing device your code takes so long to run.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan.. No like this setTimeout, Just a typo mistake

Comment: @Pointy ... I agree but its a existing framework and hardly anything can be done on this(Its actually parsing and loading template)

Comment: I don't think this will work.  Basically you are doing a ton of manipulations that don't take much "javascript time" but take a lot of "dom time" and then telling the browser, "hey, go ahead and do some browser/dom time now while I pause my javascript time."  Can you do these manipulations via some framework that has a built-in queue mechanism (e.g. jquery)?

Answer (score 0):

This is how JavaScript works, whenever you block the main thread, your site will become unresponsive to events.

You should *really* try to make parsing your templates more efficient. 10s is an eternity when it comes to UX.

If that is not an option, you could look into moving some of the logic into a different thread and execute it asynchronously via [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) and only do the actual DOM manipulation in your main thread.